# tableView's content offset changes automatically if canFocusRowAtIndexPath is set to NO

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, tvos

Problem: Scrolling to top again to tableView changes content offset and it hides first tableView cell.

I know there are lot of post on scrolling issue with tableView's scrollView where tableView content offsets changes after scrolling but there solution didn't helped me.

I tried to set content offset to 0 in -(void)layoutSubviews method but doesn't help.         Also, this doesn't help.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
self.parentViewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

In Detail:
When tableView loads, I see content offset set to {0, 0}

Printing description of $6:

```
<UITableView: 0x7fca15828400; frame = (0 0; 1920 1080); autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60800024cb40>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60800022c780>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {1920, 1600}>
```

when I scroll down, and top to again, I see offset content changed.

Printing description of $10:

```
<UITableView: 0x7fca14880400; frame = (0 0; 1920 1080); autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x618000056da0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x618000037920>; contentOffset: {0, 108}; contentSize: {1920, 3754}>
```

However, I set canFocusRowAtIndexPath to YES, I don't see problem with scrollView but I don't want tableViewCell to focused.

```
        - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canFocusRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            return YES;
        }
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was because UICollectionViewFlowLayout which I was setting programmatically and messing with content offset every time when tableView's cellForRowIndexpath is getting called.